# Showing that the set is non-empty and bounded above

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have the following exercise:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$,
> we define the set $E$ by $E=\{x=a+b: a \in A, b \in B\}$
>
> Show that $E$ is non-empty and non-bounded

I solved it but I felt like it is too trivial so I am hesitant about my solution, hence why this is in the solution verification tag.

My solution:

Assume that $E$ is empty, this implies that $a+b$ is undefined $\forall a,b \in A,B$, the only way this could happen is $\nexists a,b \in A,B$  which would imply the set is empty, contradiction with what we are given.

If $A$ is bounded then $\exists x,$ such that $x\geq a$  $\forall a \in A$ and if $B$ is bounded then $\exists y,$ such that $y\geq a$  $\forall b \in B$

Let $z=x+y$ then we have $z \geq e$ $\forall e \in E$ since $e=a+b$ and $x\geq a, y\geq b$ which means $E$ is bounded.

Note:

For the first part, I am not sure saying "$a+b$ is undefined" would be mathematically correct but I didn't find another way of putting it as even saying $a+b=\{\}$ or $a+b=\emptyset$ wouldn't make $E$ an empty set, any correction here would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why you use a contradiction for the first statement. Simply pick $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$ and $a+b$ belongs to $E$. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: but is my way correct? also, what about my note? thank you

Comment: It is very vague.

Comment: "Is undefined" makes little sense because addition is defined for all elements of the universe of discourse (here: real numbers). That's one reason why this (unneeded) extra level of proof by contradiction is suboptimal

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what would be a better word choice?